# What is the difference between () => {} and function() {} in react-native javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have seen some functions defined as `function(){}` and some functions defined as `() => {}`.

Is this related to Javascript version ES6?

Also, how does use of `this` keyword change from one function definition to another?

Comment: `() => {}` is called an arrow function.  Here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: A good in-depth article on normal functions vs. arrow functions: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `() => {}` is called an [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are, as you said, part of ES6. From the linked page:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the `this` value (does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`). Arrow functions are always anonymous.