# i have created mysql connection in nodejs it is showing database connected but showing an error as undefined database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection

var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({

```
host : 'localhost',
user : 'root',
port : '3306',
password : 'root',
database : 'test'
```

});

connection.connect(function(err){

```
if(!err) {

    console.log("database is connected"+database);
} else {
    console.log("database is not connected"+err.message);
}
```

});

[this is the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATwZ4.jpg)

Comment: It seems like database is not declared, are you sure this variable exists ?

Comment: the variable `database` in  `console.log("database is connected"+database);` is undefined, you don't have such a variable in the scope, but seems that connection is successful

Answer (score 0):

Change your connect function to look like this: (Replacing function with fat arrow function "=>")

```
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("database is connected"+database);
    } else {
        console.log("database is not connected"+err.message);
    }
});
```

This below link explains why:

[What is the difference between () => {} and function() {} in react-native javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796654/what-is-the-difference-between-and-function-in-react-native-javasc)

Comment: Have you tried removing the message? (console.log("database is connected"+database))