# How to change css display from visible to not visible after a certain time using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, display

I want to set a DOM objects css display property to 'block' for 2 seconds and then have it set back to 'none' after the 2 seconds. How can this be done in just javascript? I am really new to this so don't really get jquery just yet.

I tried

```
document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display = "block";
```

and then set it to

```
document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display = "none";
```

after some other operations but this just hides it completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setTimeout`. It will execute a method after X milliseconds. Such in your case, you will display the block & then set it back to no-display after 2 seconds.

```
method () {
  // display it
  document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display = "block";

  // hide it after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display = "none",
  2000);
}
```

Comment: () => { // code } is a shorthand for function() { // code } which was introduced in JavaScript ES6 Specification. It is used for solving a classic problem hence the 'this' scope. But since it doesn't matter here, you can use any of the two. @PumpkinBreath

Comment: @PumpkinBreath check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796654/what-is-the-difference-between-and-function-in-react-native-javasc)

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: @PumpkinBreath glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following using `setTimeout`. I suppose that by default the div is visible so I don't have to show it.

```js
setTimeout(
  function() {
    document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display = "none";
  }, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="one-rolled-popup">Testing</div>
```

But if it's hidden by default you could do this instead (click on the screen in the snippet to see the effect) :

```js
function showAndHide() {
  document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display = "none";
    }, 2000);
}



window.onclick = function() {
  showAndHide();
}
```

```css
.one-rolled-popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-rolled-popup">Testing</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```
   setTimeout(function(){ 
   if (document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display == "block";) {
      document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display= "none";
   } else {
      document.querySelector(".one-rolled-popup").style.display= "none";
   }

  }, 3000);
```